# Cant get geo location from address

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to get the geo coords for several addresses in a list like that:

```
private void setRestaurant()
        {
            foreach (Restaurant restaurant in allRestaurant)
            {
                GeoCoordinate help;
                GeocodeQuery query = new GeocodeQuery()
                {
                    GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(0, 0),
                    SearchTerm = restaurant.address
                };
                query.QueryCompleted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    foreach (var item in e.Result)
                    {
                        help = item.GeoCoordinate;

                        restaurants.Add(restaurant);
                    }
                };
                query.QueryAsync();
            }
        }
```

Because of something it cant get the geocord for any of them ( sometimes it finds one). The addresses are correct, i am sure of that , i tried them out one by one without iteration, so the bug is somewhere within this code. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: It's `Async`, so what is the value of `restaurant` when the `QueryCompleted` is returned? (The loop will likely have already ended).

Comment: Yes it is ended but it can still reach them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why:

```
foreach (Restaurant restaurant in allRestaurant)
{
     GeoCoordinate help;
     GeocodeQuery query = new GeocodeQuery()
     {
         GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(),
         SearchTerm = restaurant.address
     };
     TaskCompletionSource<Restaurant> task = new TaskCompletionSource<Restaurant>();
     query.QueryCompleted += (s, ev) =>
     {
         foreach (var item in ev.Result)
         {
             help = item.GeoCoordinate;
             task.TrySetResult(restaurant);
         }
         task.TrySetResult(null);
     };
     query.QueryAsync();
     var rest = (await task.Task);
     if (rest != null) 
         restaurants.Add(rest);
 }
```

It seems you cannot run multiple queries so you must wait before checking another address.

Comment: Yeah but how can i make it wait?

Comment: this way: `var rest = (await task.Task);` await waits any Task